# Run query from one database to another in SQL Server Mirroring set up

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, database-mirroring

We have two databases on SQL Server 2008 R2. These databases are both mirrored to a second server. DB1 runs a SELECT query on DB2.

The query assumes that DB1 and DB2 are on the same DB server, but what if one has failed over?

Currently, our code will error because the DB1 and DB2 are no longer on the same server. Is there a way to have DB1 query DB2 on whichever server it is on?